# Gradle run (using application plugin) Kotlin main function and get exit code of function

Tags: gradle, kotlin

What is the correct way to return the exit code of a kotlin main function when running it using gradle run and the gradle application plugin?

When run fails i get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/oracle-java10-jdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 100

BUILD FAILED in 35s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

With an exit code of 1. I want to get an exit code 100, just like the exit value of the task run.

My `gradle.build` only includes the the following retaliated to running:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

mainClassName = '{{PATH TO MY MAIN.kt}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to return an exit code is to use the `System.exit` function from Java
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

You may probably need to set the `mainClassName` to the `packageName.KotlinFileNameKt` to make it work. Global declarations from a Kotlin file are compiled into the JVM class called the same as the file, capitalized, with `Kt` suffix.

Comment: I am able to get an exit code then using intelij run. That's not the problem here. I also want to get the the same exit code using gradle run

Comment: Gradle `run` task is `JavaExec` task. It is not transparently turned into Gradle process exitcode. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html

Comment: How can I change it to do so?